# What is the best way in R to plot predicted values and compare interaction terms in a random effects plm model?

Tags: r, plot, interaction, plm

I have a plm random effects model that includes an interaction between a continuous and a categorical variable (for illustrative purposes, let's say the categorical variable is strong religiosity and the continuous is contribution to charity).

Here is sample data (IRL, data much larger)

```
ratio     contrib     relig    np_score     ID    year 
.4          3          1          11        1      1990  
0           7          0          8         2      1990
.9          7          1          6         1      1992
.7          6          1          10        1      1994
.1          2          0          4         2      1992
.3          9          0          8         2      1994
```

I want to plot the predicted outcomes as contribution increases depending on whether the respondent does or does not identify as strongly religious.

```r
m1 <- plm(ratio ~ contrib + relig + np_score + contrib*relig, 
            data = panel_dat, 
            index = c("ID", "year"),
            model = "random", random.method = "amemiya")
```

I have tried interaction.plot as follows:

```r
interaction.plot(panel_dat$contrib, panel_dat$relig, predict(m1), col = 2:3, lty = 1)
```

But I get the error term:

```
Error in tapply(response, list(x.factor, trace.factor), fun) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

I would ultimately rather do this with ggplot2. Any suggestions? Seems like there should be a simple answer...

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and all necessary code.

Comment: Also check out [glmmFAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#) by B. Bolker and possibly the [DHARMa](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html) package. The latter is currently lacking scientific argumentation (although it seems somewhat promising).

Answer (score 0):

This sample code produces the multiline plot below (in ggplot).  Not sure if the axes are correct ... you can adjust as needed.

```
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002),  
  ratio = c(0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6),
  contrib = c(310, 220, 230, 140, 0, 10),
  relig = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3)
)

# Build model and predictions
library(plm)
m1 <- plm(ratio ~ contrib + relig + contrib*relig, data = df, index = c('id','year'))
df$p_ratio <- predict(m1)

# Create plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=contrib, y=p_ratio, group=relig))+geom_line(size=2, aes(color=relig))
```

[image]